# sharing a resource among different servlets

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

Let's say I have a certain resource S (for instance a strange database that uses the filesystem) and I have a certain Java class R that manage that resource (it prvides high level api and manages stuff like concurrency necessary in the use of S). Now I have the constraint that if an instance of R manages S then no other instance of R can access to S at the same time.

Now, let's assume I have a servlet V1 that needs to access S through R. I want to allow many users to work with V1 concurrently, so since the container will assign a new thread of V1 to each user, I thought to make R static, initilize it in the init() method so as to share it among the threads. Is this ok?

case two: Now I have M different servlets V1,...,VM each accessible from many users. Now I want that all these servlets can have a rw access to S. I must access S through R and I can't simply use an instance of R for each servlet because only one instance at time can deal with S. Is there any way to share R among all the threads of all the servlets?

ps. R in my case is an embedded database like neo4j.

Comment: you said R manages all concurrency stuff, why not using one instance of R for all requests ?

Comment: yes that's my idea, but how to share those single instance among all the different servlets?

Comment: you can use a Static object, or a singleton one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a static initializer on R to create the one and only instance of R and store it in some static field (accessible via a static getter).

You could also create and initialize one instance of R by implementing a `ServletContextListener`. The `contextInitialized` method is called when the web app starts.

Comment: Ok so I need to create a class extending ServletContextListener, in this class I initialize R and I set a context attribute myservletcontext.setAttribute("R",R)
Then I can access it from any servlet by mycontext.getAttribute("R"), right?

Comment: ps. If then I need to close R, I can put in the contextDestroyed something like 
mycontext.getAttribute("R").shutdown() ?

Comment: You need to create a class that implements the interface ServletContextListener. Use the annotation @WebListener or update the web.xml (<listener-class>) to register the class. You can use the method contextDestroyed to close R (and then I would remove it from the context too - see removeAttribute method)